# Is there an equivalent of python's pulldom for java?

Tags: java, python, xml, sax, stax

StAX seems to be a pulling parser (like SAX but without inversion of control). But I didn't find the equivalent of python's expandNode which is what I was interested in in the first place, I don't care about inversion of control.

For those who don't know pulldom, it's a S(t)AX parser where at any point you can obtain the current subtree as a DOM Node.

Comment: Jusr curious why you don't care for inversion of control, is it because of the additional programing complexity?

Comment: By "I don't care" I mean it doesn't matter to me if the parser I'm looking for is event based rather than iterator based. I'm fine with inversion of control, even if one of the goals of stax seems to be to avoid it because it's considered more difficult.

Comment: Got it. The Java approach seems to be that either you get streaming or DOM parser but not both; while python allows mixing the two.

Comment: I put it as answer so you can accept it if there is nothing more insightful :)

Answer (score 1):

The Java approach seems to be that either you get streaming or DOM parser but not both; while python allows mixing the two.